# Coded ui ExecuteScript method is returning null when i run document.readyState from my browser object

Tags: javascript, c#, testing, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

I'm executing the below code but its returning null.  I don't know why.
When i perform the document.readyState on the browser it works.  If someone can 
point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
 object documentState;
        // check to see if browser window is finished loading
        do
        {
            Playback.Wait(1000);
            documentState = _CurrentBrowser.ExecuteScript("var myState = document.readyState;");

        } while (documentState.ToString() !="complete");
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem that i found was that i was not returning my set object.  I though that i would be able to get the object state just by getting the set state and never added a "return" keyword with the set object that i got.

Below is my updated solution.

```
      object documentState;
        // pass current browser
        do
        {
            Playback.Wait(1000);
            documentState = _CurrentBrowser.ExecuteScript("var myState = document.readyState; return myState;");

        }
```